# Por qué no respeta la dimension esta cadena en C?

Tags: c

Estoy repasando  las cadenas, dicen que toda cadena  siempre terminará en '\0'
, osea ese '\0' ocupa un espacio pero en este código yo defino dimensión 4:  nombre[4] , debería aceptar solo 3 caracteres+ '\0',pero acepta 4 caracteres??

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  char nombre[4]="Hola";
    printf("El saludo es: %s",nombre);

  return 0;
}
```

```
El saludo es: Hola
--------------------------------
Process exited after 1.077 seconds with return value 0
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

Pienso que debería arrojar ERROR desde un inicio o en su defecto 
 debería imprimir solo "Hol" pero  imprime "Hola" por que??
He probado  dev-c++ y en gcc de ubuntu 18

Comment: que versión de dev utilizaste? en la 5.11 muestra un error diciendo que no se puede inicializar el arreglo de char por el tamaño que se le está asignando

Comment: DEv-c++  Version 5.11  Built abril 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero es entender cómo funciona la memoria de un ordenador.

La memoria del ordenador se divide típicamente en bloques. Esto se hace así porque gestionar la memoria a nivel de byte consumiría demasiados recursos del equipo.

Pues bien, cuando en tu programa declaras una variable, el programa tiene que solicitarle espacio al Sistema Operativo para poder ubicar esa variable en algún lugar de la memoria. Lo que sucede entonces es que el Sistema Operativo le asigna un bloque de memoria a tu programa. A partir de ese momento tu programa tendrá acceso exclusivo a esa región de memoria y ningúna otra aplicación podrá acceder.

Resumiendo, si tu necesitas 4 bytes, el Sistema Operativo te dará un bloque de memoria de... supongamos 1KB. A partir de ese momento es tu programa el responsable de gestionar esa memoria correctamente.

Pues bien, ahora llega tu programa y lo que hace es reservar 4 bytes pero modifica 5:

```
|   nombre  | ...
 00 01 02 03 04 05
  H  o  l  a \0 ..
```

Aparentemente no pasa nada... pero es muy raro que un programa tenga únicamente una variable. Lo normal es que tenga varias variables, por ejemplo:

```
unsigned int a = 0xFFFFFFFF;
unsigned int b = 0xFFFFFFFF;
char nombre[4];
```

Dado que el compilador es libre de organizar la pila a su gusto, supongamos que la distribución elegida es la siguiente:

```
|     a     |   nombre  |     b     | ...
 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
 FF FF FF FF             FF FF FF FF
```

Si ahora escribimos 5 caracteres en `nombre`:

```
|     a     |   nombre  |     b     | ...
 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
 FF FF FF FF  H  o  l  a \0 FF FF FF
                         ^^
```

Resulta que hemos modificado el valor de `b`!!!! A partir de este punto el programa puede volverse errático. Si por ejemplo resulta que `b` es un puntero, habrás perdido la referencia a la dirección de memoria a la que estaba apuntando!!!

Pero es que además los efectos luego se pueden multiplicar, si por ejemplo ahora modificamos la variable `b`:

```
b = 0x12345678
```

Nuestro mapa de memoria ahora quedaría así:

```
|     a     |   nombre  |     b     | ...
 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
 FF FF FF FF  H  o  l  a 12 34 56 78
```

Con lo que al imprimir `nombre`, como hemos perdido el terminador de cadena (que estaba sobre `b`), lo que sucederá es que obtendremos un bonito churro de caracteres  totalmente ilegible y sin sentido.

El programa solo dejará de escupir caracteres cuando suceda una de las siguientes condiciones:

- se encuentre un `\0` en la memoria... que vete tu a saber cuándo sucede eso
- Intente acceder a una región de memoria que no pertenece al programa... el Sistema Operativo se enterará y matará el proceso para evitar que corrompa memoria de otras aplicaciones.

Así que ya ves, nada te impide escribir más valores de los que legalmente entran en un array... pero si lo haces atente a las consecuencias.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que pasa es que el que tiene que respetar la longitud es el programador :)

Cuando creas un arreglo con `char nombre[4]` estas reservando 4 bytes a partir de cierta posición de memoria (por ejemplo `0xabcd00`). Al asignar "Hola", estás llenando las cuatro posiciones de memoria, una con cada caracter.

En el momento de imprimir, la funcion `printf` imprimirá los bytes encontrados a partir de la dirección de la variable `nombre` hasta que encuentre un caracter nulo (0x00 o '\0'). En tu caso, es posible que la memoria tenga algo como:

```
Dirección | Contenido
----------------------
0xabcd00  | H
0xabcd01  | o
0xabcd02  | l
0xabcd03  | a
0xabcd04  | <Caracter nulo, posiblemente>
0xabcd05  | <mas caracteres>
```

Si los caracteres desde la posición `0xabcd04` fueran ascii, serían impresos.

---

Si pruebas este programa [(ejecutar online)](https://onlinegdb.com/rkeAqVGdr) veras el error causado por esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char hola[5] = "Hola!";
    char mundo[6] = "mundo";

    printf("%s %s", hola, mundo);

    return 0;
} // Imprimirá "Hola!mundo mundo"
```

Podríamos pensar que en memoria las variables quedaron asignadas así:

```
Dirección | Contenido
----------------------
0xabcd00  | H
0xabcd01  | o
0xabcd02  | l
0xabcd03  | a
0xabcd04  | ! ---> Aquí debería estar \0 o 0x00
0xabcd05  | m
0xabcd06  | u
0xabcd07  | n
0xabcd08  | d
0xabcd09  | o
0xabcd0a  | \0 o 0x00
```

Si uso `char hola[5] = "Hola";`, el programa imprime `Hola mundo`, como se espera. Pero si uso `char hola[5] = "Hola!";` el programa imprimirá `Hola!mundo mundo`, ya que el caracter `!` sobreescribe la última posición donde debería estar el caracter nulo `\0` de la variable `hola`, así que la funcion `printf` asume que el texto de la variable `hola` termina con el caracter nulo de la variable `mundo`

Answer (score 0):

El lenguaje C es un "ensamblador de alto nivel".

La primera parte de la instrucción de dec. de la var nombre, esto es:

`char nombre[4]`

Reserva 4 bytes en la pila.

La segunda parte de la instrucción, esto es:

`= "Hola" ;`

Copia a esos 4 bytes reservados en pila los 4 primeros bytes del literal de codigo: `"hola"` (que ocupa 5 bytes). Y como no hay espacio para copiar nada más, no copia el `\0` del final.

El terminar los Strings "C" con `\0` es un "Convención de Programación" pero NO OBLIGATORIO SIEMPRE en C. De ahí que no copiase el byte `\0`.

Si es obligatorio en la mayoria de las funciones de C de las libs estándar el terminar los strings con `\0` para saber que longitud tiene (más bien donde termina en memoria).

Por ejemplo, la función `printf` quiere que al pasar un string en algunos de sus argumentos, este string se termine en `\0`.

Por lo tanto el programa descrito, aunque no "casque" es "INCORRECTO".

Un ejemplo de programa considerado CORRECTO, y sin terminar el nombre en `\0` seria p.e. :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char nombre[4]="Hola";  // no copia/rellena con el \0 del final. PERO ES VALIDO.
    fwrite(nombre, 4, 1, stdout);  // No espera que lleve \0.
    fwrite("\r\nkkkk", 2, 1, stdout);  // Escribe dos bytes de fin de linea tipo "Windows".
    return 0;
}
```

El lenguaje C es un "ensamblador de alto nivel".